# When I create an object, what do I pass as the arguments?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have this class/function in a file named "worldmodel.py":

```
import entities
import pygame
import ordered_list
import actions
import occ_grid
import point

class WorldModel:
   def __init__(self, num_rows, num_cols, background):
      self.background = occ_grid.Grid(num_cols, num_rows, background)
      self.num_rows = num_rows
      self.num_cols = num_cols
      self.occupancy = occ_grid.Grid(num_cols, num_rows, None)
      self.entities = []
      self.action_queue = ordered_list.OrderedList()


def add_entity(world, entity):
   obj = occ_grid.Grid()
   pt = entities.get_position(entity)
   if within_bounds(world, pt):
      old_entity = occ_grid.get_cell(pt)
      if old_entity != None:
         entities.clear_pending_actions(old_entity)
      obj.set_cell(pt, entity)
      world.entities.append(entity)
```

And I have another class/method in a file named "occ_grid.py":

```
# define occupancy value
EMPTY = 0
GATHERER = 1
GENERATOR = 2
RESOURCE = 3

class Grid:
   def __init__(self, width, height, occupancy_value):
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.cells = []

      # initialize grid to all specified occupancy value
      for row in range(0, self.height):
         self.cells.append([])
         for col in range(0, self.width):
            self.cells[row].append(occupancy_value)

   def set_cell(self, point, value):
      self.cells[point.y][point.x] = value
```

If you look on the very first line of code in the body of `def add_entity`, you see that I've created an object so that I can use `set_cell`, which is a method from `occ_grid.py`. What I'm not sure about is what to pass to `occ_grid.Grid()` as arguments. Any feedback/thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: I don't entirely understand your code, but it doesn't appear to make any sense to make a new `Grid` in `add_entity` at all. Probably you want to use one of the `Grid` instances that are stored in your `WorldModel` instance, such as `world.occupancy`.

Comment: It's because add_entity uses "set_cell". (We had to modify the code in occ_grid.py, and before I made it part of the class Grid, it was a function OUTSIDE of the class) So because set_cell is now a method of the class Grid, I have to create an object in add_entity.

Comment: Sure, you need an instance, but creating one from scratch doesn't make any sense if you're just going to throw it away again. `set_cell` only modifies the `Grid`, not anything else, so if you don't need the `Grid` in the first place, you should drop the call to it as well. It *would* make some sense if you were modifying an existing `Grid`, with something like `world.occupancy.set_cell(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `def __init__(self, width, height, occupancy_value)`, you can see that `self`, `width`, `height` and `occupancy_value` need to be passed.

Now, `self` will already be put there for you but you need to pass in the other 3 like so:

```
occupancy_value = # Whatever initial value you want all the cells to have
width = # Whatever width you want
height = # Whatever height you want
obj = occ_grid.Grid(width, height, occupancy_value)
```

Comment: Ah ok. So, could I do something like: obj = occ_grid.Grid(0, 0, 0)??

Comment: Yes. However, that means you will have a 0 by 0 grid which may or may not be useful (probably not useful).

Comment: Oh wait, or, would it be more logical to make the width/height the actual playing screen's width/height?

Comment: That really depends on how the grid is being represented visually. Having taken a quick look at `pygame`'s [website](http://www.pygame.org/), it seems like having your screen width/height or at least the width/height that you want your window to be is reasonable. Having said that, I still think it depends on what these grids are representing (perhaps if I had knowledge of `pygame`, I would have look it differently).